# Spinner does not change the selection after delete

Tags: android, spinner, selection

I have a spinner with two items: (one, two) with indices 0, 1. Current selection is the first: "one" with index 0.

If I remove the this item from the spinner, the spinner should automatically move the selection to the second item "two". But what really happens is the selection remains "one" even though if I open the spinner I only find 1 option which is "two".

N.B.: the spinner doesn't even allow me to choose the "two" manually.

My guess is that after deletion, the "two" took index 0 and the spinner is marked as selected for index 0 and my action to choose index 0 again is not calling its action

Also, this behavior only happens when I have only two items in my spinner and I'm deleting the first one.

Code for deletion,

```
if(currentIndex!=0)
{
    spinner.setSelection(currentIndex-1);
}
else
{
    //deleting first item and selecting the first new item dont load its products
    spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  //selecting the 0 after deleting the 0 wont make an effect (already selected)
    selectRestaurant(0);    //this will fake the action of the seletion but the spinner has the old restaurant name
}
```

Comment: Do you create the new Adapter or update the old adapter List and calling notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: Post your code, it will helps to understand exact issue.

Comment: @BharathMg i just remove that item from the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: @Anilkumar the code is really complex i can update my question with the if statement regarding this part

Comment: @Anilkumar actually its a general question on this case if u can tell me, the code has nothing extra

Comment: @SoliQuiD Where is your deleting first item code?

Comment: @SoliQuiD do you have answer for this?

Comment: @BeeingJk this was way back ago, i can't remember